# Set mindate on datepicker in fragment android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker

I want to make mindate in mybutton that have datepicker, I tried some code but it didn't work well, I tried to add datpicker.setmin like some tutorial but it's not right too, can u guys help me how to make it works? I am so glad if u want to show me the right code.

FRAGMENT CODE

```
 private Button mAwalPeminjaman, mAkhirPeminjaman;
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_peminjaman_inventaris, container, false);

    mAwalPeminjaman = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnAwalPeminjaman);

 private void showDatePicker() {
    DatePickerFragment date = new DatePickerFragment();
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("year", calender.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    args.putInt("month", calender.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    args.putInt("day", calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    date.setArguments(args);

    date.setCallBack(ondate2);
    date.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
}

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener ondate2 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {

        mAwalPeminjaman.setText(String.valueOf(year) + "-" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)
                + "-" + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth));
    }
};
```

Datepickerfragment code

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener ondateSet;
    private int year, month, day;

    public DatePickerFragment() {}

    public void setCallBack(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener ondate) {
        ondateSet = ondate;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
        super.setArguments(args);
        year = args.getInt("year");
        month = args.getInt("month");
        day = args.getInt("day");
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), ondateSet, year, month, day);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes its answer my question, now my project is work well, thanks alot :)